# Queuing requests based on user

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, concurrency

Firstly, some background: We have a user account management system (AMS) with about 10K users. users access different websites and make purchases. the websites, in turn, rewards the users. All the transaction details, as well as the account balances, are maintained our AMS.

The AMS API receives a token and action description from the websites for:
1. purchase made by user
2. rewards given to the user by website

Problem - we noticed that during high traffic - a user is able to do multiple purchases even after his balance dips to 0. Whats happening is - the first request maybe still in process while the second one hits the system. I would like to have the each user's request go into a queue so that it gets processed properly.

Please give some definite pointers on what I should do to alleviate this pain. The system is developed with .NET / MSSQL.

Regards

Comment: How could anybody offer any real help here? We don't know how your system works currently. There are dozens of potentials here but they are all dependent on how your system works. Maybe stop using NOLOCK hints...but no clue if you are using them. Maybe using locking hints? Without a LOT more details the best anybody can do it guess. And it all sounds like it well beyond the scope of an online forum.

Comment: I know the question is somewhat vague. I am expecting solutions about using some architecture like service-bus or queues or else.

Comment: But we don't know anything about your current system we can't possibly help you find a better solution. My guess is you some design issues that is causing your system to process stuff entirely too slow. Additionally I have a feeling you are using dirty reads which would allow this exact sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using transactions in your SQL code?
A transaction would allow you to make another request for the same user wait until the first one is finished...